# Webdeploy database failing for SmarterASP host

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm trying to use webdeploy for my project to publish to SmarterASP host.  I get the following error:

> Error : Web deployment task failed. ((1/30/2018 2:55:34 PM) An error
>   occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.) 2>
>   2>(1/30/2018 2:55:34 PM) An error occurred when the request was
>   processed on the remote computer. 2>The server experienced an issue
>   processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more
>   information. 2>Publish failed to deploy.

I have gotten support to give me the error from their end:

> Content-Type: application/msdeploy  Version: 9.0.0.0 
>   MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0  MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.1981.0 
>   MSDeploy.Method: Sync  MSDeploy.RequestId:
>   42329f84-36b0-4fe3-aec5-a71745700abc  MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US 
>   MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US  ServerVersion: 9.0.1955.0  Skip:
>   objectName="^configProtectedData$"  Provider: dbDacFx, Path: data
>   source=XXXXXXXXX;initial catalog=xxxxxxx;user id=xxxxxxxx 
>   A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to
>   the client. Request ID '42329f84-36b0-4fe3-aec5-a71745700abc'. Request
>   Timestamp: '1/25/2018 8:20:58 AM'. Error Details: 
>   ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedFatalException: The SQL
>   provider cannot run with dacpac option because of a missing
>   dependency. Please make sure that DacFx is installed.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.

They claim the missing dependency is on my end.  I have installed Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (DACFx) at their request, and still have the same error.

Comment: Plesae kindly contact your hosting provider regarding this issue

Comment: I have.  They say that the issue is not on their end.

Comment: Could you please advise what application that you want to run? I see this error message 'Please make sure that DacFx is installed.' Not every shared hosting provider support this.